# How to call a code contained in the class of different Program to MVC5 APPLICATION

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to call a class from different application in my MVC5 application. 
I added the reference to my application. However, I want to call the undermentioned code from that project. How  will do that please help me.

```
IUser user = PimsLib.Config.Users.Add
(  userName
,  userPass
,  userAccount
,  encoding
,  new MappingId(1)
)
if(user == null)
   throw new Exception("Failed to add user");
```

Comment: Do let me now what do you mean by different application. Is it a different Visual Studio project within the same solution or from a different solution or totally a different program.

Comment: This call that needs to be called is different visual studio application and I am making a new one and I want to call this code In my MVC application.

Comment: Good. The different visual studio application is developed by you and you want to share code between the two. Am I right?

Comment: Yes I want to share code between the two as this code generates authentication key and I need to use only this application code

Comment: that application is not developed by me its just that i have to call that code for my application

Comment: Good. The other project code is available with you as a DLL or do you have the code for the other project?

Comment: It is available as dll

Answer (score 0):

Do follow below steps. It will help.

a) Click at your Reference node in your project, right click and Add Reference in the pop up menu appears

b) A dialogue window will appear as specified in the image, open your DLL file in the window

c) Now press OK. If the DLL is a valid DLL it will get added to the project.

[image]

Comment: Good, first step done. Could you please elaborate 'not called'. This will help to understand the specific issue.

Comment: I am developing an application in MVC5 so my question is how can I call this code that is contained in this library for my model,controllers and views

Comment: Do add using statement as follows. The using statement refers to the name space and class present in the DLL that you have imported